# How to make it so that Adsense ads do not appear on selected pages

Tags: adsense, question2answer

I am using question2answer.org CMS for my q&a website and it shows Adsense ads.
I received an email from Adsense said that I have to disallow ads from appearing on pages which contain questions and answers about some things.
I see that pages is more and receive good traffic so I do not like to remove it.
Is there any method or code to block the ads from those pages?

Answer (score -1):

The only way to disable adsense is to remove adsense code from the page. It should be done in your question2answer implementation. I've added relevant tag to your question.

Sorry, can't help you with question2answer thing, but if you are looking for some sort of configuration option or such on adsense side - there is none. You have to either remove "problematic" content from your site or adsense code from these pages.

Answer (score -1):

Insert and remove adsense code in the layout manually, via the Q&A admin section under 'layout'.